# Where put bootstrapper?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I want to create PRISM application with MVVM pattern and I don't know where I should put bootstrapper?

In Model, ViewModel or View?

Bootstrapper creates shell (so in View?) but it also registers container etc so maybe it should be like separate service?

Comment: Any of 101 posts or [articles](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2009/10/03/mvvm-with-prism-101-ndash-part-1-the-bootstrapper.aspx) about PRISM will answer you question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootstrapper is part of the executable framework for configuring your application.

I suggest putting the bootstrapper code in the OnStartup event handler of your Application class.

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen("Resources\\mysplash.png");

        splash.Show(true);

        base.OnStartup(e);

        MyBootstrapper b = new MyBootstrapper();

        b.Run();
    }
}
```

Technically, it is part of the View layer, imho, but is really there to configure the catalog and perform start-up operations.